# videojs: How to get actual text of subtitle on 'cuechange'

Tags: video.js

I'm using [videojs](https://docs.videojs.com/) with some of the following code:

```js
player.addRemoteTextTrack({ src: 'http://[somepath/to/vtt]' })
```

(I've verified that the Network tab in chrome shows a request to the VTT file and it's sound.)

And then:

```js
const textTrack = player.textTracks()[0]
textTrack.addEventListener('cuechange', () => {
  const activeCue = textTrack.activeCues[0]
  console.log(activeCue.text, activeCue.startTime, activeCue.endTime)
})
```

The `cuechange` fires during playback, but the `text` attribute doesn't contain the actual subtitle text, but instead looks like the source of the `.m3u8` file. The `startTime` and `endTime` of the cue seem to be correct though.

I think I'm missing something, but I'm trying to get the actual text of the triggered subtitle cue, but instead looks like this:

```
{"bandwidth":296728,"resolution":{"width":640,"height":268},"codecs":"avc1.42c015,mp4a.40.2","byteLength":319224,"uri":"https://...... (and so on)
```

Comment: Hmmm...I see an example here:  https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/audio-video/TextTrack/activeCues/   and it uses code like:  ...".getCueAsHTML().textContent;"   Maybe that would work?

Comment: I tried that. Returns the same string. I'm gonna try something a bit different with `player.src()`. I was using that to add only the video source, and then later add the text source. I wonder if I need to pass both video and and text sources into that method call.

Comment: Nah, that didn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Hopefully this will help someone else. It's a little confusing, but seems to be what's happening.

After I `addRemoteTextTrack()`, `player.textTracks().length` becomes 2.

- One of those is of `kind=metadata`
- The other is of `kind=subtitles` (the one I explicitly added)

I was listening on the `kind=metadata` `cuechange` assuming the remotely added track was the only one in the tracklist, and it fires off at the correct time in the video, **even without** me loading the remote text track. I think this means the stream I'm loading has some kind of `metadata` track for cue points embedded.

When I do add the remote track, trying to listen on the `kind=subtitle` track doesn't seem to fire off the `cuechange` event however, but I think this is because of [videojs track precedence](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-text-tracks.html#text-track-precedence). Neither of the tracks had `mode=showing`, so `cuechange` events only fired on the one with precedence (first item in the tracklist array... the `metadata` one).

The solution is to simply add `mode=showing` to the track that I explicitly add to give it precedence:

```js
player.addRemoteTextTrack({
  src: 'http://[somepath/to/vtt]',
  mode: 'showing'
})
```

This now allows me to listen on the tracklist item where `kind=subtitle` and get the actual text